# What's the real miscarriage risk from amniocentesis?

Tags: obstetrics, research, miscarriage

If you look for information about the miscarriage risk from amniocentesis, the risk of 1 in 200 or around 0.5 percent gets repeated again and again. Examples:

[Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/amniocentesis/basics/risks/prc-20014529)

[WebMd](http://www.m.webmd.com/baby/guide/amniocentesis)

However, they never seem to cite a source. I  am looking for a semi-current study (let's say from the last 15 years, to account for current physician training and equipment) reporting the risks of amniocentesis.

What I am looking for would also need to have a control group - one of my problems with the above mentioned sources is that while spontaneous second trimester miscarriages are a lot less likely than first trimester ones, they do occur, even without amniocentesis.

Comment: While I did end up researching more and answering myself, I'd be happy to see more answers, especially if there's a recent, controlled and large study that results in something close to the often quoted 1 in 200 number. Or a population based study larger than those I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did end up finding some recent studies with a bit more searching.

[Miscarriage risk from amniocentesis performed for abnormal maternal serum screening](http://www.ajog.org/article/S0002-9378(07)00300-6/abstract) looked at 30.000 women with abnormal serum levels and divided them into two equally sized groups, one undergoing amniocentesis and one not. They found **no significant difference** in risk of miscarriage, the risk being around 0.5 percent for both groups. According to their abstract, the study size would have been large enough to detect a jump from that 0.5 percent to 0.75 percent, so an increase by 0.25, or 1 in 400.

No statistically significant difference was also found in [Loss Rates After Midtrimester Amniocentesis](http://journals.lww.com/greenjournal/abstract/2006/11000/pregnancy_loss_rates_after_midtrimester.5.aspx), with a study group of 3.000 women and a control group of 30.000.

[Revisiting the Fetal Loss Rate After Second-Trimester Genetic Amniocentesis: A Single Center’s 16-Year Experience](http://journals.lww.com/greenjournal/Fulltext/2008/03000/Revisiting_the_Fetal_Loss_Rate_After.3.aspx) looked at a single medical center's results from 1990 to 2006. That included 12.000 women undergoing the procedure and 50.000 who didn't. The control group has a miscarriage rate of 0.26%, the amniocentesis group one of 0.4%, the difference was statistically significant. That's an **increase in 0.13%, or 1 in 769**.

At least from those studies, the risk of 1 in 200 seems overstated.